# Why does Outlook (web version) open multiple tabs when clicking a link

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook

I use the web version of Outlook in Chrome on Windows. Relatively frequently when I click on a link in Outlook it will open 2 or 3 tabs with the same page, rather than just 1. What's going on!?!? What do I need to change to get only 1 tab?

I'll note most links, either from the sender or from my institution are behind `urldefense.com` Perhaps that is part of the issue?

**EDIT:** Just happened with a link that was not `urldefense.com` which suggests this is an Outlook issue.

Comment: To exclude the influence of browser cache, test it in InPrivate mode of browser, which works without cache.

Comment: 3? Unlikely. Two on the other hand are easily explained using bad JavaScript code that opens another window. You are middle-clicking, right?

Comment: @DanielB This is left clicking. I also may be more likely to get 3 if I close one (so maybe only two simultaneously? not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information that you have shared so far:

1. Verify that Windows have installed all the critical updates.

   - Official help article from Windows Support for Windows 11 and Windows 10 [Update Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-windows-3c5ae7fc-9fb6-9af1-1984-b5e0412c556a).
2. Verify that Chrome is updated.

   - Official help article from Google Chrome Help Center [Update Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95414?hl=en).
3. If Windows and Chrome were updated, try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled.

   - Official help article from Google Chrome Help Center [Browse in private](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en).
4. If the problem disappears, then it is possible that an extension is interfering with Chrome.
5. To confirm that the problem is caused by an extension and isn't related to the browsing history,

   - Uninstall any extension and app that you don't need anymore
   - Turn off all the remaning extensions

   For details see [Install and manage extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en)
6. Close and open Chrome, and try again.

   - If the problem disappears, you should decide what you will do next, i.e. if you want to find which specific extension is causing the problem now, you might have to test one by one.
   - If the problem didn't disapear, then it's very likely that the problem is related to the browser history. You might try to delete only the data related to Outlook. If that doesn't work delete all the browsing history.

     - [View and delete browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95589?hl=en)

Comment: The problem seems to go away with incognito mode. What does that mean? I don't want to use my browser exclusively in incognito mode. Do I need to try disabling extensions? Would clearing the cache help? Seems sort of like a strange problem to be caused by the cache (not sure I follow how the two are related).

Comment: @Jimbo I suggest you to first try using Chrome in normal mode but after uninstalling all the Chrome apps and extensions that you don't need anymore and turning off all the remaning extensions (edited the answer to include this).